# CSS background-image not loading, doesn't seem to find image

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I'm making a personal website and my CSS background-image doesn't seem to be working. Link to the site is http://distorts.me/new/ it seems that it doesn't find the image because it doesn't load, it is just a white area.  (Sorry for the improper punctuation not very literate ) I'm using chrome.

style.css

```
    body {
    background-image: url("http://distorts.me/new/includes/background.png");
    color: #C0C0C0;
}

.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.row.content {height: 450px}

.sidenav {
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-color: #808080;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
}

a {
  color: #C0C0C0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #404040;
}

footer {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .sidenav {
    height: auto;
    padding: 15px;
  }
  .row.content {height:auto;} 
}
```

index.php

```
    <html lang="en">
<!-- George M. -->
<!-- 2/26/16 -->
<?php
include 'includes/head.php';
?>
<body oncontextmenu="return false" background="includes/background.png">
<header class="container-fluid text-center" style="background-color: #404040;">
    <h1>George M. - Welcome</h1>
</header>
<div class="container-fluid text-center">    
  <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav" style="height: 183%">
      <p><a href="index-2.html">Home</a></p>
      <p><a href="/about">About Me</a></p>
      <p><a href="/services">Services</a></p>
      <p><a href="/contact">Contact</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 text-middle">
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
      <p>test</p>
      <hr> 
      <h3>Test</h3>
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer id="foot" class="container-fluid text-center">
</footer>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('foot').innerHTML = 
    "<p>&copy " + new Date().getFullYear() + " Distorts | George M. All rights reserved. <span style='color: #808070;'>Made by George M.</span>"
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

head.php

```
<head> 
    <title>George M | Home</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="author" content="Distorts">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: removed the background in the body tag didn't realize it was there still doesnt work tho

Comment: what browser are you using?  I can see the bg perfectly fine on FireFox.

Comment: works in chrome too..

Comment: I also can see the background image on chrome

Comment: try after clearing the browser cache..

Comment: where do you include the css? in header.php? is that working as expected?

Comment: There is no such thing as `background` HTML attribute. *<body `background="includes/background.png">`*

Comment: @aziz like i said removed

Comment: @user3426493 your code should work as expected. I see no errors that might cause the background-image to not load. I suspect something in your browser is blocking you from seeing the image, so please, open up the devtools (F12) and check the `Network` tab and then reload the page. Look for any errors and check if the image is indeed loaded -> look at my result: http://puu.sh/nnA8I/f612b14af9.png (background.png loaded successfully - 304)

Comment: @azia http://distorts.me/imgs/files/a5c7d0b3848f644eb3ee20005aeb8605.png its getting from the old way i had it saved and i cleared my history and browser data multiple times

Comment: We should probably chat @user3426493 http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104752/azizs-room

Comment: I need 20 rep on stack to do that..@aziz

Comment: @user3426493 right... come to this https://tlk.io/azizso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the code is right, the most likely problem to be causing issues is caching. Some web hosting servers have caching preconfiguration and since you are using PHP, you can simply send PHP headers that prevent caching - add these lines at the very top of your `header.php`:

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

Another trick which can be used is `timestamping` / `querystring` - this approach basically forces the browser to reload the file since its URL is different than what it previously loaded. So naturally, we add the time variable (because time is always changing). Other developers use this method by adding a version query but that requires more maintenance.

**Adding file timestamp with PHP:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?t=<?php echo date('YmdHis');">
```

**Output**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?t=20160227182425">
```

**File version example**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?v=2.1">
```

---

Also, keep in mind that CSS background paths are relative to the CSS file itself, not HTML document. Links in html are relative to html document, links in CSS are relative to CSS file. So the correct way to reference your image is by the following:

```
background-image: url("includes/background.png");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your background url to background src :

background-image: src ("http://distorts.me/new/includes/background.png");

Comment: Doesn't fix and im using chrome doesnt load even after refreshing cache

Comment: This code is erroneous. Images in CSS backgrounds are referenced using `url(...)` and not `src(...)`

Answer (score -1):

Working fine on Chrome. Try changing your background url to:

```
background-image: src("/includes/background.png");
```

And place that image to that server rather than giving full path.

Comment: Doesn't fix and im using chrome doesnt load even after refreshing cache

Comment: Which Version Of Chrome you are Using Right Now?

Comment: Version 48.0.2564.116 m

Comment: You can Try With background-image:url ('../includes/background.png'); In css